# Generate Fake Touch in Swift 3+

Tags: ios, swift, touch, ios10

I am working on a project that has a requirement of generating a fake touch i.e I will receive few coordinates from server side and according to those points, I have to generate touch event on end-users device.

What I have tried so far is **PTFakeTouch.framework** but it is not giving me the output as required in iOS_10+. 
If anyone has worked on the same Kindly do let me know.

Comment: were you able to find a solution? I think I have the same problem

Comment: Yes, **PTFakeTouch** only, I have executed that in **Xcode 8** and its working fine, No bit code issue, nothing.

Comment: Will Apple Approves it??

Comment: did you find solution for this? I'm facing same problem

Answer (score 0):

Usually you do not need to fake a user interaction.. just perform the resulting action of what would happen when this event occurs. I.e. if the user was to add a pin on the map when tapping and on receiving coordinates from the server you want the same, just add a pin at the desired location.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but what I need to implement is whenever I receive some coordinates then action should happen like in **team-viewer** or I can say screen controlling of end user.